# Open source iOS torrent client

Tags: open-source, ios, bittorrent

I'm looking for an open source iOS torrent client that can open Magnet links and download torrents on the device itself.

Note: Just "monitors" for computer-based torrent software aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: How do you want to export it from the device when you're done downloading the torrent?

Comment: @Undo no export required, just to open it in another app directly (a video player which I already have installed).

Comment: I'm intentionally leaving this question very broad as there aren't many solutions anyway, I found none at least.

Comment: For android, f-droid suggests frostwire saying that upstream is not free. They don't seem to hvae an iOS version yet. https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=torrent&fdid=com.frostwire.android

Comment: did you try Deluge

Answer (score 1):

From their site: *[Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/) is a fully-featured cross-platform ​BitTorrent client. It is ​Free Software, licensed under the ​GNU GPLv3+ and adheres to ​freedesktop standards enabling it to work across many desktop environments.*

It has many addons and several browser plugins that will work out for you.

Some of it's plugins:

- CopyMagnetURI addon
- Copy Completed
- BitTorrent WebUI+
- OSX Magnet URI Handler

Browser plugins:

Chrome

- **DelugeSiphon:** Ultra simple Chrome extension to add torrents via WebUI interface.
- **Deluge Remote:** Provides a simple overview of current torrents within Chrome ​(Source Code)

Firefox

- **BitTorrent WebUI+:** Automatically add torrent/magnet links via WebUI
- **WebUI Quick Add Torrent:** Uses Greasemonkey to add a clickable icon on webpages for adding torrents via WebUI

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/ioshomebrew/iTransmission-4. I'm not sure about magnet links, but it's a full torrent client which stores the files on the device itself. I will never find it's way into the appstore, but if you compile it for yourself (which I guess is what you want to do) with Xcode, it should do what you need.

Comment: Not only does this state it will never be accepted in the AppStore, you seem to need to compile it with an SDK + *Cydia*, so we've ruled out most iOS users (I assume) and made it complex. I wouldn't suggest this as an "answer" unless the OP was already Jailbroken and ready to compile.